# Dynamically inject instance by subdomain

Tags: asp.net, dependency-injection, asp.net-core, multi-tenant

I have the following ActionFilter in order to create/store a TenantFeature:

```
public async Task OnActionExecutionAsync(
            ActionExecutingContext context,
            ActionExecutionDelegate next)
        {
            // figure out tenant configuration 
            // create tenant feature 
            context.HttpContext.Features.Set<ITenantFeature>(tenantFeature);
            await next();
        }
```

Then i have a base controller where i defined the following property:

```
  public TenantConfig TenantConfig => Request.HttpContext.Features.Get<ITenantFeature>()?.TenantConfig;
```

I don't really want to pass this `TenantConfiguration` down to Application/Domain layers.

I'm looking for a way to create a injectable configuration (per request) in that `OnActionExecutionAsync` method. Looks like something plausible?

In order to be able to do something like:

```
public DatabaseProvider (TenantConfig tenantConfig) { }
```

P.S: I know that all services are defined in Startup.cs.

P.S 2: Tenant configuration is dynamic so i cannot register that at startup.

Comment: Can you show the code for ITenantFeature and TenantConfig that show in what way they are dynamic?

Comment: Basically we can consider that I fetch my tenant config information from a tenant management application (outside provider).

Comment: Please show it.

Comment: I parse current route, try to get a tenant name, then call an external provider for tenant config. I have my app deployed once for all tenants.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up creating an `Autofac` module and registering the following instances:

```
 builder.Register(cc =>
            {
                ITenantIdentificationStrategy s = cc.Resolve<ITenantIdentificationStrategy>();
                s.TryIdentifyTenant(out var tenant);
                return tenant;
            }).As<ITenant>().InstancePerLifetimeScope(); 

 builder.RegisterType<TenantFeature>()
                .As<ITenantFeature>().WithParameter((pi, c) => pi.Name == "tenant", (pi, c) => c.Resolve<ITenant>()).InstancePerLifetimeScope();
```

Implementation was inspired from the following package: https://github.com/autofac/Autofac.Multitenant

`TryIdentifyTenant` method is checking the subdomain and figures out current tenant.